# Why am I sometimes getting inaccurate latitude and longitude values from CLLocationManager?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;


if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
{
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

}
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy<0)
    {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    else
    {
        NSTimeInterval interval = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

        if(abs(interval)<15)
        {
//Here i am doing my code but i get location which is far from my current location last time maximum distance i got from the current location was near about 3000 meter

            [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        }
    }
}
```

i use this code but not getting the location accurate some time it gives more than 1 km away from current location 
i want accurate location

Comment: just update question with app delagates file CLLocationManager method.

Answer (score 3):

When you first ask for location updates you may get a "stale" location from the last time the GPS was active. (I've seen stale location readings that are several kilometers off.) The first fiew locations also tend to have poor accuracy.

You should check the date stamp on the locations you get and reject any that are older than 1 second old, and also reject those who's accuracy reading is larger than your desired accuracy.

### EDIT:

Your `didUpdateToLocation` method does not make sense.

When you call `startUpdatingLocation`, you will get location updates as the location changes, until you call `stopUpdatingLocation`

There is no reason to call  `startUpdatingLocation` inside your `didUpdateToLocation` method, because the location is already being updated. In fact it might mess things up. Don't do that.

In pseudocode, what you want to do is something like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
  if the time of the update is > 5 seconds old, return.

  if horizontalAccuracy < 0 || horizontalAccuracy > 500, return. 

  stop updating location.
  
  do whatever you want to do with the location.
}
```

When you return without doing anything, you'll get more location updates as the GPS settles down.

I use 500 as the maximum acceptable accuracy reading as an example. That would be .5 KM, which is a lot of error. A smaller number like 100 or 50 would give better results, but take longer.

Comment: Thnkyou @Duncan C  but can u give me one example for that

Comment: Take a look in the docs and see if you can figure out how to do what I'm suggesting. Take a look at CLLocation. Is there a timestamp? Is there an accuracy reading? (Hint, it's called horizontalAccuracy). How might you check for stale location readings? Wildly inaccurate ones? Try to code it yourself, and if you can't get it working, edit your question with the code you came up with and we'll help you debug it.

Comment: your solution worked for "getting cache location" but what for location i get are the  500 meter away from my current location

Comment: hey i edited the code plz check and let me know where i am wrong

Comment: u talk that take 'stale' location that is location before 1 second but form morning i am on one place and i did not changed my location thereafter it takes location 3000 far from my current location so there is no meaning of taking stale location if evevn i didn't change my location

Comment: Your new code doesn't make sense. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: When you first call `startUpdatingLocation`, the location manager sometimes gives you the last location reading it took when the GPS was active. That old location can be minutes or hours out of date, and have a location that is multiple kilometers away from your actual location. That is what I meant by a "stale" location.

Comment: thanks a lot it works,only the problem is some times it takes time or some times it does not give any location then how should i handle this problem

Comment: i used" startupdatinglocation" because the didupdateToLocation called 3 to 4 times so i am not able to get locationif the location are not updated

Comment: how can i take the location only through the GPS i dont want the location from the wifi or the cellular network?

Comment: You can't. The device integrates inputs from GPS, WiFi and cell networks to come up with location readings. All you can do is reject readings that don't meet your accuracy requirements. Sometimes you CAN'T get a reading accurate enough in a reasonable time, and you have to put in logic to handle that case as well.

Comment: - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    
    
        NSTimeInterval interval = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

        if(fabs(interval)<5)
        {
            if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 0 && newLocation.horizontalAccuracy<100)
   {
   }
}

Here i am not getting most of the time the accurate location so how does the other application shows the right location within few minutes where i am not able to  get the location

Comment: i am not getting the location right it get the location in between 500 mtr but not accurate and if i mangaed minimum harizontal accuracy minimum than 500 then i dont get the any location coordinates